# get text of linklabel created at runtime

Tags: c#, text, get, properties, linklabel

can someone please explain to me how i can get the Text property of the linklabel that i have created at runtime?

I have tried:

string str = e.Link.LinkData;

...but that just displays an empty messagebox.

Thanks lots :)

Comment: e.Link.Description returns a blank string, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Now that we know the type of `e`, try:

```
string str = e.Link.Description;
```

If the `LinkLabel.Link` doesn't have enough information, you'll have to refer to the `LinkLabel` itself. That *may* be the sender of the event (as suggested by MusiGenesis) but if it's not, I suggest you use a lambda expression or anonymous method to subscribe to the event - that way you can capture the `LinkLabel` and refer to the `Text` property directly.

Comment: private void llabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            string str = e.Text;
        }

Yes Mr Skeet, I have. But it comes up with a squiggly red line under 'Text' when I use the above code.

Comment: If you'd explained the type of `e` to start with, that would have helped. Editing...

Comment: I just tried this, and e.Link.Description returns a blank string.

Comment: It's possible that it was accepted due to the "capture" part of the answer. Hard to say.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a mysterious "e" in your code, I assume you're trying to do this in the LinkLabel's LinkClicked event.  To do this, you need to cast "sender" as a LinkLabel, like so:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, 
    LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    LinkLabel lnklbl = (LinkLabel)sender;
    string str = lnklbl.Text;
}
```